# how do i edit the PATH variable to include a variable

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, path, cron

I have a shell script in place and have been using an independent ssh agent to login into various machines and the do the required. Now, the problem is that I have been trying to add this script to the cron job but it does not work for some reason. I think this has something to do with the PATH variable and including the independent ssh agent as a part of that variable and exporting it in the .bash_profile

This is what my .bash_profile looks like:

```
PATH=$PATH:usr/local/bin/rssh

export PATH
```

And my script has the following path at the top:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

What am i Missing over here to declare this independent variable and get it working using a cron job.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `.bash_profile` won't affect a cron job. If the cron job executes your script, you can modify your script so that it sets `$PATH` itself, internally.

Comment: ...or just put the full path to the commands in the script instead of trying to rely on the path which is set in your local environment, not where `cron` will find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo, instead of using

```
PATH=$PATH:usr/local/bin/rssh
```

try :

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

Missing `/`

and you can't add the full command path but just the dir where reside the command.

Last thing, add

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

in your script to ensure the script will look-up the new PATH.

Comment: In fact you *can't* enter the command; each item in `$PATH` has to be a directory (or it will be ignored).

Comment: will `cron` know where `~/` is?